# use anchor tag to open a static page in worpdress

Tags: anchor, permalinks

I have one page site which have blog section, and a blog page which will include all blog posts. When I click in particular posts read more button, it redirects me to single.php page. But when I click on View all blog post button , it redirects me to blank blog page with 0 comments page . I want it to redirect to blog.php page. I have already created page-blog.php for it.

Comment: Add more details, add some code you've written etc. Otherwise the question might get closed by the moderators or people will have a hard time helping you.

Comment: <a href="http://localhost/myportfolio/blog/" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large load-more">See More</a>

Comment: i have used above code to see more blog page and  the below code to go for the particular posts.   <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="brand-text right waves-effect">Read More</a>